# How to use ORDER BY inicio::timestamp DESC with UNION?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use ::timestamp in a UNION clause, but it's not working, basically I have these two columns process1 and process2, it always follows a pattern, if there's a data in a row in column process1 the row in column process2 goes be empty, and if we have data on a line in process2 the line in process1 will be empty.This "inicio" column is a datetime column and I always use  ORDER BY inicio::timestamp DESC  to sort my columns to the most current date and time, but with UNION it's not working, could you please help me?

```
SELECT process1, inicio FROM public.table1 WHERE id = '1'
UNION
SELECT process2, inicio FROM public.table1 WHERE id = '1'
ORDER BY inicio::timestamp DESC
```

Comment: The ORDER BY sorts the complete UNION result.

Comment: Perhaps 1 select with select coalesce(process1,porcess2)

Comment: Show us some sample data and the expected result, as well as the actual (unwanted) result. A [mcve].

Comment: Show the explain plan will be most helpful.

Comment: Avoid using "but it's not working",

Comment: If `inicio` is already a timestamp, then the cast to a timestamp is pretty much useless

Comment: Note that the ORDER BY will sort the result of the entire UNION after all duplicates have been removed. It does not apply to just the second query.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you mean NULL for empty but if so

```
SELECT coalesce(process1,process2), inicio 
FROM public.table1 
WHERE id = '1'
ORDER BY inicio::timestamp DESC
```

and It's not clear why you thought a union would be useful or what not working means..

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner and I didn't know about "coalesce", thank you so much for your help, it's working now